# Align selected tags to right Kendo Multi-Select?

Tags: javascript, css, kendo-ui, multi-select, kendo-multiselect

I am using [kendo multi-select](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/index) for implementing a tag based selector component. In that, by default any selected tag will appear left aligned. You can see the picture I have attached

[image]

Is there any way to configure them to right aligned??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this style in your page:

```
.k-multiselect ul li.k-button {
    float:right;
}
```

Or use it as a class if you don't want to change the behaviour of all MultiSelect widgets in your page.

Comment: perfect (Y) (Y) btw isn't there anyway in config level of the widget? :))

Comment: @SupunWijerathne I don't think so.